# Bitbucket в Xubuntu

Tags: netbeans, bitbucket, xubuntu

**Xubuntu**, стоит **Netbeans 8.1** - попытался клонировать в него свой репозиторий с **bitbucket**. И каждый раз выдает при попытке `pull/push` окно **Specify Git repository location** с **Repository URL** https://bitbucket.org/username/nameofrepository.git. Не могу понять что подправить, с Git работает без проблем, в Windows тоже с **Git** и **Bitbucket** проблем нет. Хочу понять что тут не так?

Comment: а если делать pull с консоли в xubuntu, то все работает как нужно?

Comment: Да, через терминал все работает корректно - поэтому я и в замешательстве - пока вот так и кручусь. А хотелось бы удобно, чтоб прям из IDE, минуя терминал

Comment: у меня есть предположение, что конфиг, где netbeans хранит это просто "read only". А может у них и баг. Я лично пользуюсь везде только терминалом (плюс meld для просмотра диффов) и то, как реализовали это в конкретной иде меня тревожит.

Comment: Ясно, если так - оч жалко, придется с бакетом через терминал тогда видимо

Comment: я к ним в [багтреккер](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?component=Git&product=versioncontrol&resolution=---) заглянул... Я даже не знаю, как можно пользоваться.